# switching between different versions of GROOVY in the ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I got installed Groovy on ubuntu . I do have option of 2 versions installed - 1.7 & 2.0

Ubuntu command - 
$ groovy -v
  Groovy Version: 2.0 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

Currently groovy version is pointed to 2.0 but I need to SWITCH to 1.7 version & I don't want to remove 2.0. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

So the quite universal tool (not only for Groovy) is [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/). The usage can be found [here](https://sdkman.io/usage).

After the installation of groovy versions which you are interested in, execute:

```
sdk list groovy
```

It will show all possible versions (and mark those which are already installed on your machine). Sth like below:

```
================================================================================
Available Groovy Versions
================================================================================
     3.0.5               2.4.14              2.1.9               1.7.10         
 > * 3.0.4               2.4.13              2.1.8               1.7.9          
     3.0.3               2.4.12              2.1.7               1.7.8                 
     .....
================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
```

And for example, if you need the version 3.0.4, you just call

```
sdk use groovy 3.0.4
```

After that the result should be like this:

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 3.0.4 JVM: 14 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use [gvm](http://gvmtool.net/).

When you install groove 2.0 and 1.7 with gvm, then you `gvm use groovy 1.7` fro switch on 1.7 version, and after `gvm use groovy 2.0` for 2.0.

2) Also, if you have installed 1.7 version, then print `which groovy` and see where you have installed 2.0 version, after in you `bashrc` redefine `groovy=/path/to/1.7/bin/groovy`
and change `PATH` variable:

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/1.7/bin

But the best way it use a `gvm`